# "master" branch missing revisions after sequential "git svn fetch" calls

Tags: git

I initialized a Git repository with: `git svn init https://path/to/proj`

Then I updated my .git/config file to specify the locations of the branches/tags:

```
fetch = cascade/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = cascade/branches/{feature-branch1,feature-branch2}:refs/remotes/*
branches = cascade/branches/{6.x,5.x,4.x,3.x,archive}/*:refs/remotes/*
tags = cascade/tags/{3.7.x,4.x,5.x,6.x,old-releases}/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Then, I fetched the revisions 5000 at a time:

```
git svn -r1:5000 -A/path/to/mapping/file fetch
git svn -r5000:10000 -A/path/to/mapping/file fetch
git svn -r10000:14000 -A/path/to/mapping/file fetch
git svn fetch
```

The problem is that after all that `git log` tells me that the last revision in my master branch is the one mapped from svn revision 5000. What gives?

Comment: if you do gitk --all what do you see? where are the latest revisions under? You can also git grep to see where things landed. You should be able to stitch the history back together with git rebase --onto and grafts.

Hope this helps,

Adam

Comment: I'm starting to think that the -r flag is not doing what I think it's doing.

Comment: try putting the options at the end of the line and put a space between the 'r' and the revision range. I would also just do it with one fetch instead of doing these ranges. To make it faster, do a hotcopy backup of the SVN repo and then make the backup folder the svn remote. This will allow you to do all this locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"fetch" does not merge the changes into your master, that's why you're not seeing them. After performing those commands, do a final `git svn rebase`.

Comment: That appears to be the case, but how come a "git svn fetch" on it's own WILL merge the changes into my master branch.

Comment: Does it always do that? I use git-svn the whole time (it's awesome), and it doesn't for me - except, as I found out when answering your question, when the repository is still completely empty.